# Laravel: Notify admin when user do something

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, notifications

I will explain my idea. When a default user does an action, I want the admin to be notified about this action. To do this, I use notifications in **Laravel** that are saved in the database (I don't know if this is the better way).

My problem is that i can't show the notifications with an admin user.

When a user does a specific action, I want all the admins to be notified:

```
$admins = Admin::all();<p>
foreach ($admins as $admin) {
    <p>$admin->notify(new RepliedToThread($acao));<p>
}
```

Next, I want to show the notifications on a navbar in my dashboard (only admins have access).

I did that with:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        Notificações <span class="badge"> {{Auth::admin()->unreadNotifications() }}</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><p>
        <li>
            @foreach (Auth::admin()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                {{$notification->type}}
            @endforeach
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I don't know if I did this in the best way or if it will work. For now I have this error:

> Method admin does not exist

But I want help with the entire process, not just this error because I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set up an admin guard, you may use:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications())
```

But if you're using the default web guard, then you should access unread notifications like this:

```
$user->unreadNotifications()
```

But then again, it depends on how you've set up your admins.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that error, within your blade template you are calling Auth::admin() and there isn't an admin method on the Auth facade. If notifications are common to all users, then you should be able to do Auth::user()->unreadNotifications() instead (providing an unreadNotifications method exists on your user model).

Regarding listening for changes and notifying admins, I would recommend you look into Events, an explanation of which can be found on the Laravel website: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events

Comment: what5 tou think about Pusher fotr my objective?

Comment: I've got no experience with Pusher sorry. As I say I think Events may be a good option for what you are trying to do.